# How can I validate the image pixel?

Tags: jquery, html, validation

How can I validate the image pixel?
 Below is my code, but for image type and size only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Image Validation</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery validation plug-in - comment form example</title>
    <script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/file-validator.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cssval.css">
    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Image</legend>
            </p>
              </li>
              <li>Choose an image file:
                  <input type='file' class='demo' data-type='image' data-max-size='2mb' />
              </li>
        </fieldset>

    </body> </html>

</head>
```

Comment: Im trying to add this but no luck: document.getElementById('your_form').onsubmit = function(){
    var uploadImage = document.getElementById('upload_field').value;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = uploadImage;
    img.onload = function(){
        if(this.width>200||this.height>400) {
            alert('Your image is too big, it must be less than 200x400');
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is with jquery I thnk you have to preview img first whatever hidden or not and after preview use that code see [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128634/jquery-file-upload-preview-image) and [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/LvsYc/1669/) and after preview use that code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var imgWidth = $('#target').width();
 var imgHeight = $('#target').height();
 if(imgWidth > 400 || imgHeight > 200){
 alert('Your image is too big, it must be less than 200x400');
}
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by hidden? I will try this thankyou.

Comment: I meant if you don't want your users whose upload images to show preview .. just hidden display:none that div

Answer (score 1):

Use this inside you script

var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

```
    function readURL(input,index) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {

               $('#user_img_preview').attr('src', e.target.result);  // You can show image preview before submit


          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
   $("#user_img").change(function (e) {

      // Check file is image or not
      var file, img;
      if ((file = this.files[0])) {

        var fileName = this.files[0]['name'];
        var idxDot = fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
        var extFile = fileName.substr(idxDot, fileName.length).toLowerCase();
        if (extFile=="jpg" || extFile=="jpeg" || extFile=="png"){

          readURL(this,1); 
          img = new Image();
          img.onload = function () {

              if(this.width != 100 || this.height != 110) {
                alert('Please upload proper image with exact size : 100 x 110');
              } 
          };
          img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);

        }else{

          alert('Only jpg/jpeg and png files are allowed!');

        }

      }
  });
```